# Create custom Seq collection in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I want to create a new custom Scala collection from existing `Seq` collection. I have a trait named `Ref` which holds the data as below

```
trait Ref[A] {
   def get: A
   def getAsOption: Option[A]
   def dataType: Class[A]
   // other methods
}
```

My custom collection named `Vec` which is a `Sequence` of `Ref[A]` (i.e `Vec[A]` equivalents to `Seq[Ref[A]]`), the reason I want to create a custom collection like this because I want to keep the type parameter of `Ref` in collection to process in custom methods. My code as below

```
trait VecLike[A, +Repr <: Seq[Ref[A]]]
  extends SeqLike[Ref[A], Repr]
  with TraversableLike[Ref[A], Repr] {
// custom methods
}

trait GenVec[A]
  extends VecLike[A, Seq[Ref[A]]]
  with Seq[Ref[A]]
  with PartialFunction[Int, Ref[A]]

abstract class AbstractVec[A](vec: Ref[A]*)
  extends AbstractSeq[Ref[A]]
  with GenVec[A] {...}

class Vec(vec: Ref[A]*)
  extends AbstractVec[A](vec:_*)
  with VecLike[A, Vec[A]]
  with GenericTraversableTemplate[Ref[A], Seq]
```

But when I call `map()` function

```
Vec(1,2,3,4).map(intToString)
```

It returns a `Seq[String]`, the expected result is `Vec[String]`. I also tried to create custom `CanBuildFrom` in companion object with `SeqFactory[Seq]` but it failed. :( :(

Can anybody give me some advices about this and how I implement to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement a custom `Builder` and make `newBuilder` method in `VecLike` return it. 
Check out this page for a very good tutorial on implementing custom collections: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html

Comment: I was going to appreciate the author of this comment and then realised it is from @Dima. What a coincidence? Oh, thiis, is the best answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I finished it, that's my mistake I created wrong CanBuildFrom. Below is the full implementation with CanBuildFrom (CBF Inspired from Scala GenericCanBuildFrom)

```
trait VecLike[A, +Repr]
  extends SeqLike[Ref[A], Repr]

trait GenVec[A]
  extends AnyRef
  with VecLike[A, GenVec[A]]

trait Vec[A]
  extends GenVec[A]
  with VecLike[A, Vec[A]]

abstract class AbstractVec[A](vec: Seq[Ref[A]])
  extends AnyRef
  with Vec[A]

final class VecImpl[A](vec: Seq[Ref[A]])
  extends AbstractVec[A](vec)

object Vec {


  private[this] val VecCBFInstance: VecCanBuildFrom[Nothing] = new VecCanBuildFrom[Nothing] {
    override def apply() = newBuilder[Nothing]
  }
  private def VecCBF: VecCanBuildFrom[Nothing] = VecCBFInstance
  private class VecCanBuildFrom[A] extends CanBuildFrom[Vec[_], A, Vec[A]] {
    def apply(from: Vec[_]) = newBuilder[A]
    def apply() = newBuilder[A]
  }
  implicit def canBuildFrom[A]: CanBuildFrom[Vec[_], A, Vec[A]] = VecCBF.asInstanceOf[VecCanBuildFrom[A]]

}
```

Now I can receive Vec result instead of Seq after call map() function as below

```
val vec = Vec(1,2,3,4)
var vecStr : Vec[String] = vec.map(intToString)
```